# python easy_install eggs from a list of eggs

Tags: python, easy-install, egg

in a `./eggs/` folder I have eggs files and file eggs.txt with the list of filenames.

I would like to install all this eggs in this folder.

Can I do something like ?::

```
$ easy_install -r eggs.txt
```

for now I've nothing better than::

```
$ for i in `ls *.egg`; do easy_install $i ; done
```

Comment: So what's the problem with the `for` solution? That's the whole point of shell scripts

Answer (score 1):

The egg format, and the `easy_install` tool for installing from eggs, are both becoming obsolete. They are being replaced by [the Wheel format](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/) and [the Pip package manager](https://packaging.python.org/pip_easy_install/#pip-vs-easy-install).

What is creating those eggs? Are you able to switch to the currently-supported Wheel format, or the still-supported Sdist format?